# Confused about how to get CheckedListBox checked items count

Tags: c#, winforms

I am populating checkedListBox  with some value on form Load event .

```
checkedListBox1.Items.Add("one");

checkedListBox1.Items.Add("two");

checkedListBox1.Items.Add("three");
```

What I want to do is to click some of them and show a messagebox how many chekbox is clicked.The problem is that message  returns  "0" everytime for both  SelectedIndexChanged and   SelectedValueChanged events.more interestingly ;I  need to click twice to tick checkbox and then message box shows the  right results. What is wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Property Called CheckOnClick for CheckedListBox. Set it to True, and all your problem will be solved.